# Maven dependency version dependent on JVM version

Tags: java, maven, jetty, pom.xml, alpn

I'm trying to create a Maven POM which will pull in [the correct version of alpn-boot](https://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-versions) when building the project and running the tests.

The whole thing works if I'm injecting the property from "outside" when running the build (e. g. via `mvn -Dalpn-boot.version=8.1.8.v20160420 test` or as an environment variable) but not when trying to interpolate it inside the POM using `${java.version}`.

I've tried using [properties-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) to accomplish this with the following settings in the `pom.xml` file (snippet):

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>${project.basedir}/alpn-boot/jdk-${java.version}.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty.alpn</groupId>
      <artifactId>alpn-boot</artifactId>
      <version>${alpn-boot.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Contents of one of the properties files:

```
$ cat alpn-boot/jdk-1.8.0_92.properties
alpn-boot.version=8.1.8.v20160420
```

Basically the same problem with the `gmaven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>execute</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <source>
          alpnVersions = [ '1.8.0_92': '8.1.8.v20160420' ]
          project.properties['alpn-boot.version'] = alpnVersions[System.getProperty('java.version')]
        </source>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

With both approaches I get the following error message:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.mortbay.jetty.alpn:alpn-boot:jar must be a valid version but is '${alpn-boot.version}'. @ org.example:my-project:[unknown-version], /path/to/pom.xml, line 132, column 22
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.example:my-project:1.0.0-rc3-SNAPSHOT (/path/to/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.mortbay.jetty.alpn:alpn-boot:jar must be a valid version but is '${alpn-boot.version}'. @ org.example:my-project:[unknown-version], /path/to/pom.xml, line 132, column 22
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

Comment: What is the big issue to write the version into the pom literally ?

Comment: @khmarbaise The problem is that the build/tests hang and fail if the "wrong" version of the JVM is being used. Unfortunately I'm running another version of the JVM on my development machine than for example Travis CI does and so I have the choice between my builds failing or builds on Travis CI failing if I hard-coded the version of "alpn-boot" inside the POM.

Comment: That sounds like a job for maven toolchains...and apart from that if your build hands with a different JVM ? (7/8?) than you should check your code..Furthermore anything of the jvm is available via environment. And using different dependency based on JVM/JDK used sounds you need [a profile which is activated by JDK version](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)..

Comment: @khmarbaise "My" code is fine, it's just that `alpn-boot` works by patching some classes of the Java runtime and thus is dependent on the version of the JVM.
Thanks for the hint with Maven profiles. It's a bit more verbose than I hoped it would be (given that there are 8 different versions of `alpn-boot´ for different versions of Java 8), but it looks feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up following [the advice of @khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363352/maven-dependency-version-dependent-on-jvm-version#comment62256059_37363352) and add a [Maven profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for each version of the JDK which needs to be supported:

```
<properties>
    <!-- Default alpn-boot version. See <profiles> for specific profiles. -->
    <alpn-boot.version>8.1.3.v20150130</alpn-boot.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty.alpn</groupId>
        <artifactId>alpn-boot</artifactId>
        <version>${alpn-boot.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!-- Profiles for selecting the correct version of alpn-boot for each JDK.
     see http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html for reference. -->
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jdk-1.8.0</id>
        <activation>
            <jdk>1.8.0</jdk>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <alpn-boot.version>8.1.0.v20141016</alpn-boot.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- Lots of profiles [...] -->
    <profile>
        <id>jdk-1.8.0_92</id>
        <activation>
            <jdk>1.8.0_92</jdk>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <alpn-boot.version>8.1.8.v20160420</alpn-boot.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```